# How to reuse Angular directive in an ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular-directive

I have an ASP.NET MVC application with a lot of Areas and models, views and controllers inside them. I have a small calculator that I want to write in Angular because it will be easier for me, as a developer, and cooler for the user (instead of using jQuery only).

The thing is I want to have this calculator on different views in some of my areas in the MVC app. The best solution that I could came up with is make an Angular directive and then use it in every view that I need it. My question is whether this will work and whether I would have to make a different Angular module for every view that  will use the directive.

Any better solutions and proposals are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Example from Angular documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

```
phonecatApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/phones', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-list.html',
        controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'
      }).
      when('/phones/:phoneId', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-detail.html',
        controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/phones'
      });
  }]);
```

you can config as many controlles that you like per page(html). and each htm will include your custom calculator directive.

All the controllers can be registered to the same module:

var phonecatControllers = angular.module('phonecatControllers', []);

```
phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
  function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('phones/phones.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.phones = data;
    });

    $scope.orderProp = 'age';
  }]);

phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams',
  function($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.phoneId = $routeParams.phoneId;
  }]);
```

Comment: I want to use the calculator in different ASP.NET MVC views, not Angular views.

Comment: Hi, its the same in ASP.NET MVC, please check the following example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/806029/Getting-started-with-AngularJS-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Par

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on it: You don't need a separate module per view. If you are only using this to provide your calculator directive then you could just do something like:

```
angular.module('calculator', [])
    .directive('onscreenCalculator', function () { ... });
```

I don't know if you are using partial views, but if you are it could be problematic if you use the `ng-app = "calculator"` directive at the view level. Personally, I would put it in your `_Layout.cshtml` and then you **know** you're only going to have one instance.

Your biggest challenge (in my opinion) is going to be how to get the result of the calculation back into your view since you're not truly writing an Angular app, but just using a directive. I'm sure it can be done with some playing around, though.